# Boot problem with 12.10 from DVD

Tags: boot, 12.10, boot-failure

I'm a Ubuntu newbie and I did a search on this problem without any luck but I do think that it might be a simple one.

I created a ISO boot DVD and at the start it looks like it works perfectly as I get the Ubuntu logo and it runs for some time but then it freezes up and ends up with the message

```
acpid: client connected from 2818 [0:0]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
acpid: clinet connected from 2830 [0:0]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the world of ubuntu, the way itself is the light, so enjoy it (;

first i'd recommend you use a boot able USB which you can create with [UNETBOOTIN](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) on windows. its a better solution because you don't have to burn a new DVD for every version, its faster, and you can reuse the stick aftwerwards. (but, you need a free 1gb stick) try it again, it may have been just a read write failure on the DVD. (simply plug it in, change your primary boot device to something like USB-DISK | FDD and voilà)

have fun, and let us know how it worked, spheniscida